# Set gradle temporary directory to SSD

Tags: android, windows, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using android studio with gradle. When I build the app, I notice the spinning harddisk is working a lot, so I looked and saw that gradle is writing temporary files to the directory defined (in Windows (8.1)) the variable `TEMP` or `TMP` under my user.

**Is there some way I can change the directory gradle uses as temporary directory without changing it for all other applications as well?**

I would like to move the gradle temp dir to an SSD. (Bonus question: do you think this would significantly speed up gradle, that is currently very slow)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to set environment variable `GRADLE_OPTS` to `-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\some\dir\on\sdd`, and `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to `D:\other\dir\on\ssd`. Also make sure that the project directory is on SSD.

Comment: Do I have to reinstall gradle or do something else after I set these environment variables? Looks like cmd `SET GRADLE_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=P:\Gradle\temp"` didn't worked for me (folder is empty). But `SET GRADLE_USER_HOME="P:\Gradle\home"` works.

Comment: It looks like I have now 2 gradles, one for Android Studio and from IntelliJ, because in Android Studio you have to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453793/can-i-move-the-android-studio-s-gradle-folder-to-other-disk

Answer (score 2):

In your`build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = "c:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"     
}
```

Here is the full example code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {


        buildDir = "c:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
        repositories {

        }


    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Bad answer since the build dir is already on a "supposedly" SSD drive: "c:/tmp". Nothing in this answer mentioned how to relocate the gradle workdirs to a folder on an SSD drive.