# Can I move the Android Studio 's .gradle folder to other disk?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I use the windows system,and I find after I install Android Studio,it will create the folder .gradle in my system disk,and this would occupy my a part of space,so I want ask whether I can move it to other disk,and whether would have disadvantage.Thank you.

Answer (score 40):

Open Android Studio,

go to **File > Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle**

In Global Gradle settings

Change **Service directory path** to the desired folder.

Save the setting.

Now close Android Studio and move the .gradle from your C drive to the location you have chosen.

I have my .gradle on my second HDD (so that's how i did it)

Comment: You means choose the offline  gradle and set it path with my new folder which in other disk ?

Comment: @wavever You can use the offlne .gradle, however the file path also works for the online .gradle as well

Comment: Android Studio uses `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable to determine the default location. This value can then be changed in Android Studio settings per project.