# Move Android Studio .gradle project folder

Tags: android-studio, gradle, google-drive-shared-drive

How Can I move .gradle folder in my Android Studio project to another location?

I already tried Refactor - Move Directory, which succeeds in moving but on the next build the .gradle directory is recreated.
I also tried removing access rights, but then gradle just fails to build (instead of using a temp directory)

The directory interferes with Google Drive as it changes a lot and Drive tries to upload lots of files on every single build, so I want to have it outside of the project structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I move the Android Studio 's .gradle folder to other disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453793/can-i-move-the-android-studio-s-gradle-folder-to-other-disk)

Comment: That question covers the `.gradle` file in the user's home directory, but I think this question is asking how to move the "Project-specific cache directory generated by Gradle". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575542/set-gradle-cache-directory