# Gradle Daemon Initialization script failed unexpected token ' in username

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I downloaded the latest version of Android studio and created a new project, but it seems that I can't get it to work since the Gradle Daemon is failing because my windows user has a comma **'** . My username also has a space, but I guess that I shall see if I will get another error when I reach there.

Any settings that I can do to bypass this problem, without changing my user name?

[image: received error image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I had an idea and I found a possible solution:

The solution is a mix of these 2 questions:

[Set gradle temporary directory to SSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881148/set-gradle-temporary-directory-to-ssd)

[Android Studio missing essential plugin org.jetbrains.android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682609/android-studio-missing-essential-plugin-org-jetbrains-android)

**1. Change Gradle temp files to another directory**

Create a new folder ex: D:\some\dir\

Go to System Properties and edit the Envitonment Variables.

Add **GRADLE_OPTS** with -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\some\dir\

Add **GRADLE_USER_HOME** with D:\some\dir\

**2. Remove disabled_plugins.txt file**

Go to the following path and delete the file:

**C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioVersion\disabled_plugins.txt**

**3. Re-create the project**

Answer (score 0):

You could try various hacky things like setting your `GRADLE_USER_HOME` and `TEMP` environment variables to folders outside your user space (e.g. `C:\gradle` & `C:\temp`).

However, you're going to be fighting against Gradle / Android / the entire build process now and forever! I'd really really recommend instead using a name without special characters. If this isn't possible, perhaps a new user with a simple name would be a quick fix.